# Fluent NHibernate - Mapping a dictionary of component/value type objects as a HasMany

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, dictionary

I have a class, `Item` that has many `Rates`.  They are keyed by an enum, `RateType`.

```
public class Item
{
    int Id {get;set;}
    IDictionary<RateType, Rate> Rates {get;set;}
    // some other stuff
}

public class Rate
{
    RateType Type {get;set;}
    decimal Amount {get;set;}
    decimal Quantity {get;set;}
}
```

I am overriding my mapping thusly:

```
public void Override(FluentNHibernate.Automapping.AutoMapping<Item> mapping)
{
    mapping.HasMany(x => x.Rates)
        .AsMap(x => x.Type)
        .KeyColumns.Add("Item_Id")
        .Table("InvoiceItem_Rates")
        .Component(x => x.Map(r => r.Amount))
        .Component(x => x.Map(r => r.Quantity))
        .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
        .Access.Property();
}
```

This has two problems with it.

1)  When I fetch an item, the `Type` is placed as the key of the Dictionary without problems.  However, it is not assigned to the `Type` property within the `Rate`.

2)  I'm expecting three columns in the table `InvoiceItem_Rates` (`Item_Id`, `Type`, `Quantity`, and `Amount`.  However, `Amount` is suspiciously absent.

Why are these things happening?  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't perfect in my opinion as the enum key value is actually being stored as an integer instead of a string, but probably isn't an issue.
The key here is that you can't have multiple calls to Component as it's going to overwrite your previous Component call with whatever the last one is.
The correct way to call Component() is as below:

```
        Id(x => x.Id);
        HasMany(x => x.Rates)
            .AsMap(x => x.Type)
            .KeyColumn("Item_Id")
            .Table("InvoiceItem_Rates")
            .Component(x =>
                           {
                               x.Map(r => r.Amount);
                               x.Map(r => r.Quantity);
                           })
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan();
```

Comment: Well, I'm getting data back, and that's the most important thing.  However my `Type` property still isn't being returned.  I tried adding it to the components, but I got an error "Repeated column in mapping for collection".  But that's another problem altogether!  Thanks!